# Does Titanium support XMPP?

Tags: titanium, xmpp, titanium-mobile

The question says it all, I know there are xmpp projects written in node.js and JS, but from what I've seen it looks like Titanium only has a chat substitute with TCP.

Answer (score 1):

Not out of the box. But you can wrap an existing XMPP / Jabber client like [ChatSecure](http://chrisballinger.info/apps/chatsecure/) (which is free an open-source) in a [Titanium module](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/iOS_Module_Development_Guide) and use it.